# Ubuntu Wayland setting appearance

Tags: xorg, wayland

If I click to setting appearance in Ubuntu Wayland 22.04.2 lts , it shows 1️⃣ icon, what is the error?[[image]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMTpW.jpg)

Comment: You have "1" notification. RightClickHold for info, LeftClic to Open.